Sending multiple emails iterating through a list using microsoft.graph c#
I have a program that has a datatable containing email addresses.  I want to iterate through the table and send an email to the recipient.   The code I have works fine if I send only 1 email with no for loop.  As soon as I try to loop through, no emails get generated.  I think it is my lack of understanding on the async methods and how I'm supposed to use Microsoft.graph
Code snippets below.
In the button click method:
SendEmail("mailer@xxxx.xx.xx`your text`", dtEmail);
// (Note there is a CS4014 warning here)

SendMail method:
static async Task SendEmail(string fromAddress, DataTable dtEmail)
{

    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    var tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"];
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
    var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];

    // using Azure.Identity;
    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

   var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
   var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

   string Subject = "Email notification";

   var htmlBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Path to the HTML File");

    // Attachment 1
    var file1 = "path to the attachment";
    byte[] fileArray1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@file1);

    
    foreach (DataRow row in dtEmail.Rows)
    {
        var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
            {
                Subject = Subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = htmlBody,
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                     Address = row["Email"].ToString(),
                    },
                },
            },
                Attachments = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment>
            {
                new FileAttachment
                {
                    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                    Name = "MemberNotice.pdf",
                    ContentType = "application/pdf",
                    ContentBytes = fileArray1,
                },
               
            },


            },
            SaveToSentItems = false,
        };

        try
        {
            await graphClient.Users[fromAddress].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
        }
        catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there is an error");
        }
       
    }

}

No emails get generated.  There should be multiple emails generated

The CS4014 warning should tell you everything. Your code isn't running because you aren't awaiting it.

Thanks David, can you please advise what needs to change in my code in order to await it.

Yes do this: await SendEmail(....);

I am calling the SendEmail from within the Button_Click method .  If I add the await SendEmail, I need to change the button click method to  public async task btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).
I don't know the implications of this or if that is correct?
And then my next question:  Once I iterate through the datatable and send the emails - how do I know that the process is complete if it is sending asyncronously?

Hi @DavidG.  Thanks for the updated code.  I have implemented and it works.  Please confirm how do I know that the job is finished.  Can I assume that when the for loop completes it is done even though the emails can still be running in the background?
